# getting all events for a date from multiple calendars errors after loop

Tags: forms, calendar, spreadsheet

In our office, we share and post to several calendars that track different events/activites. I wrote a code that allows someone to fill in a Google Form with the date of the events they want to see and checkboxes of which calendars to pull from. In its current incarnation, the script errors after the first loop through (or as it's attempting to getEventsForDay() for the second calendar). I can't figure out why.

The process: user response to form goes to first sheet of spreadsheet. Script activates upon form submit and pulls all the events of the calendars that were listed on the date that was inputted. The script lists the Calendar, Event Title, Event Start Time and Event End Time on the second sheet. The user has the option of printing that sheet (as a worksheet with which they would do a daily audit of events)

Where I get my error (TypeError: Cannot call method "getEventsForDay" of undefined) is in the line below, after a successful first pass through the first calendar listed:

var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(thiscals)[0].getEventsForDay(when);

Here's the code:

function onformsubmit() {

```
 var today = new Date();
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var response = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheets()[0]);
 var endrow = response.getLastRow();
 var responsedatarange = response.getRange(endrow, 1, 1, response.getLastColumn());
 var responsedata = responsedatarange.getValues();
 //variables below are pulled from the spreadsheet
 for (i in responsedata) {
     var info = responsedata[i];
     var when = info[2];
     var allcals = info[3];
     Logger.log(when + ' ' + allcals);
     }
 var whichcals = allcals.split(',');
 var report = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var reportsheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(report.getSheets()[1]);
 reportsheet.clearContents();
 var header = [["Which Calendar", "Event Title", "Event Start", "Event End", "Audit Notes", "Record Start?", "Record Saved?"]];
 var range = reportsheet.getRange(1,1,1,7);
 range.setValues(header);
 for (var i = 0; i < whichcals.length;i++) { 
     var thiscals = whichcals[i];
     var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(thiscals)[0].getEventsForDay(when);

     if (calendar[0] != null){
       for (var j = 0; j<calendar.length; j++) {

                        var eventlist = [[thiscals, calendar[j].getTitle(), calendar[j].getStartTime(), calendar[j].getEndTime(),' ' ,' ' ,' ' ]];
                        var endrow = reportsheet.getLastRow();
                        var writerange = reportsheet.getRange(endrow+1, 1, 1, 7);
                        writerange.setValues(eventlist);
                        }
                    }
       }
```

}

Thanks for any guidance. I'm fairly new to Google App Script, so I know I have plenty to learn about syntax, classes and such.

Comment: I think the culprit is this line: var whichcals = allcals.split(','); -- it takes all the calendars indicated in the form (as represented by allcals) and splits them into an array (whichcals[i]). I think it's introducing a space before the name of the calendars after the first one, so when the CalendarApp service goes to look for the named calendar, it can't find it. What do you think?

Comment: figured out a workaround. After var whichcals = allcals.split(''); I added thiscals = whichcals[i].substr(1) to remove the leading space that was added to all subsequent thiscals after the first loop.